# User with same permission not getting similar search result as other user in sharepoint 2007

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, crawling

I am having an issue where a user is not getting exactly the same search result as other users in the team. The user joined the team recently and I granted permission through adding her into a Sharepoint Group.

In practical sharepoint wont show list/documents if the user doesnt have any access to that paticular list/library. So, I compared the list/library shown for the user in **View all sites content** page with other users and all seems to be exactly same.

The crawler is successfully working fine as well.

Does anyone came across similar situation? or have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The crawler works - have at least one incremental crawl completed since you added the users?